# need help configuring rails4 logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I'd like to analyze the logs of a rails4 app we're working with - using request-log-analyzer - and so far

```
Parsed lines:        1373                                                
Skipped lines:       1373                                                
Parsed requests:     0                                                   
Skipped requests:    0 
Warnings:            teaser_check_failed: 182791, no_current_request: 26155


There were no requests analyzed.

Parse warnings
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parsable lines were encountered without a header line before it.
```

it skips all lines.  The only change I've made in the config for logging is to prefix a subdomain (config.log_tags = [ :subdomain ] in app/environments/production.rb).  I tried removing it, though, and still no parsing.
An example of the way the log files look is below, and I'm using this command to parse them: request-log-analyzer --parse-strategy assume-correct --format rails --file o production.log.  FYI running with puma and nginx.

Does anyone know what I have to do to get the logs in shape for request-log-analyzer to parse them?

```
[kingscliff.adventist] Started GET "/site/Title_Banner_-_Children_s_Ministry.jpg" for 199.30.25.137 at 2015-06-20 03:49:29 +1000
[kingscliff.adventist] Processing by SitesController#show as JPEG
[kingscliff.adventist]   Parameters: {"path"=>"site/Title_Banner_-_Children_s_Ministry"}
[www] Started GET "/site_data/109/assets/0038/1971/Gender_Action_Guide_Combined.pdf" for 180.180.74.76 at 2015-06-20 03:49:29 +1000
[www.signsofthetimes]   Rendered /app/varticles.html.erb (37.7ms)
[www] Processing by SitesController#show as PDF
[www]   Parameters: {"path"=>"site/Gender_Action_Guide_Combined"}
[www.signsofthetimes]   Rendered shared/_css_and_js_includes_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
[www.signsofthetimes] Completed 200 OK in 1765ms (Views: 1636.0ms | ActiveRecord: 100.2ms)
[sydneychinese.adventist] Started GET "/" for 23.229.34.148 at 2015-06-20 03:49:29 +1000
[www]   Rendered sites/disabled.html.erb (0.9ms)
[www] Filter chain halted as :current_site_disabled? rendered or redirected
[www] Completed 200 OK in 73ms (Views: 11.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
[sydneychinese.adventist] Processing by SitesController#show as HTML
[kingscliff.adventist] Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 121ms
```